# Remove duplication Jquery code is not working on all dropdown on my MVC form

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I am using a jquery code found on Stakeoverflow to remove duplication value in the dropdown. my problem is the jquery code worked for the first dropdown but will not work for the second dropdown any help will be welcome

1st dropdown

```
<select id="AssetStoredWhere" name="AssetStoredWhere" class="form-control js-example-disabled-results 
     select">
   <option value="@ViewBag.AssetStoredWhere">@ViewBag.AssetStoredWhere</option>
   <option value="UK">UK</option>
   <option value="EU">EU</option>
   <option value="Worldwide">Worldwide</option>

</select>
```

2bd Dropdown

```
<select asp-for="Dpiaavailable" id="Dpiaavailable" name="Dpiaavailable" class="form-control js- 
   example-disabled-results select">
   <option value="@ViewBag.Dpiaavailable">@ViewBag.DpiaavailableValue</option>
   <option value="False">No</option>
   <option value="True">Yes</option>
</select>
```

Jquery code

```
var seen = {};
jQuery('.select').children().each(function () {
    var txt = jQuery(this).attr('value');
    if (seen[txt]) {
        jQuery(this).remove();
    } else {
        seen[txt] = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need another loop to iterate through the `select` elements themselves, not through the `option` elements of every `select` as one. Try this:

```js
$('.select').each(function() {
  var seen = {};
  $(this).children().each(function() {
    var $option = $(this);
    if (seen[$option.val()]) {
      $option.remove();
    } else {
      seen[$option.val()] = true;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Rory for your help

Comment: No problem, glad to help